# Run Main Tasks parallel and Sub Tasks sequential/dependent

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, multitasking

So I have a use case where I have 5 main tasks, inside the main tasks there are 3 sub tasks (say asynchronous I/O operations). The main tasks are independent while the sub tasks within a single main task are dependent of each other. I can run all of the tasks sequential but it would be a huge wastage of CPU time.
I need a way to use async-await and Promise to run all the main tasks parallel and inside each main task run the sub asynchronous tasks sequential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came with using vanilla JavaScript `async` `await` and `Promise`

```js
async function myFunc() {
  const list = ["MainA:", "MainB:", "MainC:", "MainD:", "MainE:"];
  let allPromises = [];
  list.forEach(main => {
    allPromises.push(runSubTasks(main));
  });
  console.log("allPromises before settle:", allPromises);
  let data = await Promise.all(allPromises);
  console.log("allPromises after settle:", allPromises);
  console.log("resolved values inside allPromises:", data);
  // All main tasks are done by this point
}

myFunc();

async function runSubTasks(main) {
  const one = await asyncSubTask1(main, "");
  const two = await asyncSubTask2(main, one);
  return asyncSubTask3(main, two);
  // or
  // const three = await runTask3(main, two);
  // return three;
}

function asyncSubTask1(main, sub) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`${main}${sub}1`);
      res(`${sub}1`);
    }, Math.random() * 10000);
  });
}
function asyncSubTask2(main, sub) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`${main}${sub}2`);
      res(`${sub}2`);
    }, Math.random() * 10000);
  });
}
function asyncSubTask3(main, sub) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`${main}${sub}3`);
      res(`${main}${sub}3`);
    }, Math.random() * 10000);
  });
}
```